# Image into submit button

Tags: php, html

Need some help getting the images into submitbuttons.

I am using a while loop to fetch multiple images from database and in the same time trying to create a form with a submitbutton displaying the image for each new image fetched.

I can't use CSS to have an image as a submitbutton since I am fetching multiple images with mysql to create multiple submitbuttons.

This explains what I'm trying to do. And btw, it has to be done in PHP, not javascript.

```
<?php 

$connect = mysql_connect("host", "user", "password") or die ("didn't con to db");
mysql_select_db("database") or die ("Couldn't find db");

$query = "SELECT  `Image` FROM database WHERE Genre='$genre'";

if ($query_run = mysql_query($query)) {

    while ($query_row = mysql_fetch_assoc($query_run)) {  

        $image = $query_row['Image'];
        $info = $query_row['Info'];
        $comments = $query_row['Comments'];
?>

    <form name=Form4 action="nextpage.php" method="post">  
        <input type="hidden" value="<?php echo $info; ?>" name="Info" />  
        <input type="hidden" value="<?php echo $comments; ?>" name="Comments" />  
        <input type="submit" class="imagebutton" value="<?php echo $image; ?>" > 
        <img src="<?php  echo $image; ?>" alt="" height="92" ></> 
    </form> 

<?php

//end of loop
    }
} else {
  echo 'Query failed. (something wrong in the code)';
}

?>
```

Comment: It doesn't display the submitbutton as an image.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems your code have syntax error. Your code is like this

```
<img src="<?php  echo $image; ?>" alt="" height="92" ></>
```

Note that tag `img` is like this `<img />`, not this `<img></>`